# Is this region bounded?

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

I have the following regions: $S_1=\{(x,y,z):2az=x^2+y^2\}$ and $S_2=\{(x,y,z:x^2+y^2-z^2=a^2\}$ with $a>0$.
I'm trying to find the volume of region bounded by $S_1$ and $S_2$ as the book says, but it seem that is not bounded:

The plot for $a=1$
[image]

I wonder if the exercise is wrong and I need more restrictions, because I only found one curve of intersection between the two regions.
What I did was taking $S_1$ and $S_2$  to have $x^2+y^2-2az=x^2+y^2-z^2-a^2$ which is equivalent to $z^2-2az+a^2=(z-a)^2=0$. Then I have as intersection a circle at height $z=a$
It seems that I'd need to introduce another restriction to have a bounded region, am I missing something?.

Also, are cylindrical coordinates apropiate to calculate a solid that could be bounded by $S_1$ and $S_2$?

Comment: Are you sure you want the volume of $S_1\cap S_2$, and not the volume of the (finite) region of space whose boundaries are $S_1$ and $S_2$?  That region looks like an hourglass.

Comment: Thanks @vadim123 !. You're right, I edited the some parts of my question.
But wouldn't I need $S_1 \cup S_2$ to know the boundaries?.
And I still find it hard to picture because $S_1$ seems to be above $S_2$ and have nothing but the a circle in common, then having no bounded region by both. Wouldn't I need more conditions, like being the solid bounded by $S_1$, $S_2$ and two planes to have a solid?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mis-understanding the meaning of the word 'bounded'. In this question, it does not mean that the space you are trying to find the volume of is itself 'bounded' (in the sense of lying within some finite ball), only that you should cut $\mathbb{R}^3$ along $S_1$ and $S_2$, and look at the piece that touches both of them.

Take a cross-section with constant $z$-value, as at the top of the picture included. You see two concentric circles. You are interested in the annulus between them, and all the other annuli you get by doing this for different values of $z$.